# Delete row in listview with imageview

Tags: android, listview, imageview

How do I implement the delete row on listview. I would like to able delete the row when user click the 'x' (imageview). 
The code is here:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                    String str = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    ImageView ivDel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivClose);
                    ivDel.setOnClickListener(
                                    new OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "delete" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                    });
                }

            });
```

The 'x' button only worked on the first row, the rest is not functional.

[image]

Comment: How did you load listview use simpleadapter or customadapter

Comment: http://pastebin.com/K29dSyjk here are my whole class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    int position = listview1.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
    yourList.remove(position);
    yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

1

```
 public interface DeleteListIteamListner {
    void itemDeleteListner(int position);
}
```

2

```
yourActivity implements DeleteListIteamListner 
 youAdapter adapter = new youAdapter (yourActivity);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

3 in youAdapter ,

```
DeleteListIteamListner  listner;
   public youAdapter (yourActivity listner){
       this.listner = listner;
   }
```

then when you click delete imageView:

```
ImageView ivDel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivClose);
                    ivDel.setOnClickListener(
                                    new OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                              listner.itemDeleteListner(position);  
                                            }
                                    });
```

and in youActivity

```
@Override
    public void itemDeleteListner(int position){
yourList.remove(position);
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "delete position is "+ position , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the 3rd part. Here are my whole class. http://pastebin.com/K29dSyjk